# When using asyncio.Queue() how do I cancel the gets?

Tags: python-asyncio

I'm writing a client in asyncio and using q.get() to wait for responses from the server. When I receive a response from the server I put it on the queue.  If the server connection is lost I will no longer being doing those puts and could have any number of await q.get()'s hanging around.

How should I cancel them?  I noticed that when I delete the queue the await gets are still waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this look like what you are trying to do?  You have two options I think:

If you keep a count of outstanding gets then when you are done with the queue you can just put(None) that many times?

Or if None is a valid response then keep a list of the outstanding futures and call cancel on them yourself.

```
import asyncio

async def qget(q):
  try:
    x = await q.get()
    q.task_done()
    print("qget done ",x)
  except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
    print("qget cancel exception ",e)
  except Exception as e:
    print("qget exception ",e)

async def run():

  q = asyncio.Queue()
  futs = []
  futs.append( asyncio.ensure_future( qget(q) ) )
  futs.append( asyncio.ensure_future( qget(q) ) )
  num = 2

  await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

  # Keep the number of outstanding gets and put None for each one
  if 1:
    for x in range(num):
      q.put_nowait(None)

  # Or keep the futures in a list and cancel them
  if 0:
    for f in futs:
      f.cancel()

  await asyncio.sleep(1)
  print("run loop done")


asyncio.run(run())
```

If you look at [the python code for the queue](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/queues.py) it does keep a list called _getters, but there is no public api for accessing it.

Comment: You can put None only once, but make it so that when a worker dequeues None, it adds it back to the queue and only then exit. That way None will be observed by all workers without knowing in advance how many of them there are. (This trick also works with multi-threaded queue.)